# Do locally soluble and the maximal condition on subnormal subgroups imply soluble?

Tags: group-theory

Here is an interesting question.

Let $G$ be a locally soluble group. We know that if $G$ satisfies $Max$ (the maximal condition on subgroups), then $G$ is trivially soluble. On the other hand, if $G$ satisfies $Max_{n}$, we know that $G$ CAN be insoluble.

Now, we have that $Max<Max_{sn}<Max_{n}$, so how does $Max_{sn}$ act like? Can we say that all locally soluble groups with $Max_{sn}$ are soluble or does it exist one of them which is not?

[This question is in the area of looking for similar behavior of different properties in similar context. In this case, for example, $Max=Max_{n}$ for locally nilpotent groups]

**Definitions**

*Locally soluble*: Every finitely generated subgroup is soluble

**$Max_{sn}$**: Every chain of subnormal subgroups of $G$ is finite

**$Max_{n}$**: Every chain of normal subgroups of $G$ is finite

Comment: The following paper seems to prove that in our case either $\;G\;$ has all its subgroups subnormal or else it is soluble by finite-minimax: http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/119553/CommentatMathUnivCarolRetro_46-2005-4_2.pdf Not quite solves your problem, yet it gives some ideas...perhaps.

Comment: Yes, I know that paper, but it is about (weak) **minimal** on **non** subnormal subgroups. In that case everything works fine

Comment: Perhaps you should try to ask in MathOverflow, for research level questions.

Comment: And then it's unnecessary to start with "Here's an interesting question" (since you wouldn't ask it if you don't think it's interesting) :)

Comment: Well, I find it really interesting :D Maybe I should try there, uhm. If I do so, should I remove this question from here?